# Member functions called on non-pointer objects with std::function

Tags: c++, std-function, this-pointer

Code is as the following.

`std::string::empty()` should take the `this` pointer as the parameter whose type is **pointer**, `std::string *`.

How could the calling at line `2` and `3` be OK?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::string str{"A small pond"};

    std::function<bool(std::string*)> fp = &std::string::empty;
    std::cout << fp(&str) << std::endl; // 1

    std::function<bool(std::string)> f = &std::string::empty;
    std::cout << f(str) << std::endl; // 2

    std::function<bool(std::string&)> fr = &std::string::empty;
    std::cout << fr(str) << std::endl; // 3
}

/*
output:
0
0
0
*/
```

```
clang version 9.0.0-2~ubuntu18.04.2 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
g++ (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I modified the title.

Comment: `str.empty()` is legal. Wrapping that call inside `std::function` is okay, too.

Comment: @PeteBecker How to explain it from the view of syntax or type conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` can accept any *Callable* that matches its type signature. When invoked, the callable and arguments are evaluated with the following rules (quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)):

> - If `f` is a pointer to member function of class `T`:
>
>   - If `std::is_base_of<T, std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>>::value` is `true`, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to
>       `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)`
>   - If `std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>` is a specialization of `std::reference_wrapper`, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is
>       equivalent to `(t1.get().*f)(t2, ..., tN)`
>   - If `t1` does not satisfy the previous items, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)`.

So the first case is evaluated like `(*t1).*f()` and the other two are evaluated like `t1.*f()`.